# Finding the second derivative using DFT

Tags: numerical-methods, approximation-theory, fast-fourier-transform

Suppose  you have an **even real-valued** function f(x), which is periodic with T=2L. Introducing a grid
$$x[n]=-L+ndx,\quad f(x[n])\equiv f_n,$$
$$dx=\frac{2L}{N},\quad n=0,\ldots N-1,$$
its DFT is defined via
$$F_k=\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}f_n\cos\left(\frac{2\pi nk}{N}\right).$$
I've actually checked that its inverse transform returns the original signal:
$$f_n=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}F_k\cos\left(\frac{2\pi nk}{N}\right).$$
As far as I understand, the approximation of the second derivative of such a function is given by
$$f_n''=-\frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}\left(\frac{2\pi k}{N}\right)^2F_k\cos\left(\frac{2\pi nk}{N}\right).$$
However it doesn't match the value of second derivative of a function in any sense:

[image: 1]

I've seen a similar topic, but I'm trying to figure it out without using built-in FFT.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution to this problem although I do not fully understand it. First of all, the mentioned derivative has factor $1/(2L)^2$ instead of $1/N^2$:
$$f_n''=-\frac{1}{N}\sum\left(\frac{2\pi k}{2L}\right)^2F_k\cos\left(\frac{2\pi nk}{N}\right),$$
which can be clearly seen if taken the derivative correctly with respect to x, it was a strightforward mistake. However it doesn't solve the problem. I've tried to reorganize my sum as follows:
$$f_n''=-\frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=-N/2}^{N/2-1}\left(\frac{2\pi k}{2L}\right)^2F_k\cos\left(\frac{2\pi nk}{N}\right)$$
and somehow it worked! It would be great to see the explanation for this.